# How do I programatically download a file from a sharepoint site?

Tags: c#, file, download

I have a sharepoint site that has an excel spreadsheet that I need to download on a schedulad basis

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not just use `wget.exe <url>`. You can put that line in a batch file and run that through windows scheduler.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible to download the file from sharepoint.
Once you have the url for the document, it can be downloaded using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse.

attaching a sample code

```
    DownLoadDocument(string strURL, string strFileName)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);
            request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.Timeout = 10000;
            request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();

            // Write to disk
            if (!Directory.Exists(myDownLoads))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(myDownLoads);
            }
            string aFilePath = myDownLoads + "\\" + strFileName;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(aFilePath, FileMode.Create);
            byte[] read = new byte[256];
            int count = s.Read(read, 0, read.Length);
            while (count > 0)
            {
                fs.Write(read, 0, count);
                count = s.Read(read, 0, read.Length);
            }

            // Close everything
            fs.Close();
            s.Close();
            response.Close();

    }
```

You can also use the GetItem API of Copy service to download a file.

```
        string aFileUrl = mySiteUrl + strFileName;
        Copy aCopyService = new Copy();
        aCopyService.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        byte[] aFileContents = null;
        FieldInformation[] aFieldInfo;
        aCopyService.GetItem(aFileUrl, out aFieldInfo, out aFileContents);
```

The file can be retrieved as a byte array.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
try
        {   
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "DOMAIN");
                client.DownloadFile(http_path, path);                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The link the to document in Sharepoint should be a static URL. Use that URL in whatever solution you have to grab the file on your schedule.

Comment: Is there software out ther that will do this?

Comment: wget as answered above will do this.